# How can I bind fieldName_1, fieldName_2 to a list in spring mvc

Tags: spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I'm trying to convert a struts 1 application to Spring MVC 3.0. We have an form with quite a few parameters, most of which where automatically binded in struts. However there where a number of fields in the format fieldName_# where # is a number that we manually bound by looping through the request.

I'm looking for a tidier way to do this in Spring mvc, but don't know where to start.

Ideally we should have them as fieldName[#] and it would be easier, but we cannot change this and have to keep the fieldName_# format. Also the number of these fields that are sent in the request are unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by wrapping the servletRequest and implementing the getParameter (and associated methods) such a way that parameters with name fieldName_# are returned as fieldName[#].  A servletFilter would be one option to wrap the request.